# to provide access from one account to the data of another

Tags: php

I'm going to develop a multiuser system, where people can register an account, log in, store and manage the data of the account. For example, email address idetifiers a user.
Could you tell, please, how to provide the user of one account  access to the data of another account. For example, by providing a link in the account that gives access to another account.
It looks like Google Analytics uses a mechanism similar to this one to give access of one user access to the account of another user.
Thanky you very much, Oleg.

Comment: Umm, you... do it? There's no simple answer to a question of how to build a whole big feature, especially without knowing anything about how your project is set up.

Comment: There's more than one way to query a database.  Or, in this case, share data.

Answer (score 2):

Providing code will be impossible here but, I'm going to guess at your setup and we'll see what happens.

So, you perhaps have a users table and a data table.

One option, is to allow Private and Public options on the data table. Public can data can be accessed by anyone.

The other option is to have another table `dataPermissions` where you associate data ids to user ids. When listing data, if the data item isn't owned by the current user, they must have a corresponding entry in the `dataPermissions` table.

Remember though, providing code and examples of you database structure is the best way to get a good answer.

**Update**
Okay, so we know that `users` are identified by `email` and can have one or many `links` to `data`. Those `links` can be shared to other `users`. Therefore, you are going to have a table for `users`, identified by `email`, and a table for `data` which is identified by its `link`.

Therefore, a `user` can choose to add more `users` to a `link`. For this, you would need a new table that associated `users` and `links`, i.e. a `userLinks` table.

Comment: I was just typing almost the exact same response. +1

Comment: The data looks like this.
There users (identied by email). There are accounts that stores user's data. Every user has at list one account (which is created during registration). How to let grant the user access to other account of the site. For example, after logging in the user has links that gives access to other accounts.